# Unable to delete erlang builds with kerl

Tags: erlang

I've installed Erlang using kerl. I've built it as 32bit and not 64bit as I should've. Trying to correct my mistake is proving problematic.

```
./kerl status
```

brings me

```
Available builds:
R15B01,r15b01
----------
Available installations:
----------
The current active installation is:
/Users/jason/erlang/r15b01
```

Then when I try to

```
./kerl delete r15b01
```

or

```
./kerl delete R15B01
```

I get

```
No build named r15b01
```

and

```
./kerl build R15B01 r15b01
```

gives me

```
There's already a build named r15b01
```

So I cannot rebuild and I cannot delete the old one.
I know I am most probably missing something very obvious, but I am new to this and cannot find anything on this.

thanks!

Comment: what are the results of kerl list build?

Comment: ./kerl list R15B01
    Cannot list R15B01

    ./kerl list r15b01
    Cannot list r15b01

Comment: `strace ./kerl list 2>&1| grep -i "*r15"` yield anything?

Comment: @ZephyrPellerin Nope, just blank.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the syntax for deletion. You need to specify the type of delete you are doing before specifying the actual build.

Instead of...

> kerl delete build_name

You should type...

> kerl delete **build** build_name
>   kerl delete **installation** path

To get a list of already installed builds or installation paths that you can delete type:

> kerl list builds
>   kerl list installations

Comment: I've tried various permutations: 
./kerl delete r15b01 R15B01
Cannot delete r15b01 
/kerl delete R15B01 r15b01
Cannot delete R15B01

Comment: What he's saying is that you have to type the actual word "build", not the build name, followed by the build name. Same goes for removing installations. So you should type "kerl delete build r15b01"

Comment: Ah, I see. I've moved on since so I can't really test this now. Seems like it should be correct - should I mark it as so?

Answer (score 0):

To list the registered installations:

```
kerl list installations
```

To delete one of them:

```
kerl delete installation /full/path/from/above
```

Use the absolute path here like shown in the list command.

If the delete command fails, you can also delete the line of the installation in the file `~/kerl/otp_installations, which is not an oficial solution. Remember to also delete remaining files of the installation manually.